# How to disable saving CallKit calls in history

Tags: ios, objective-c, privacy, callkit

I'm using CallKit in my Objective-C app.

My problem is that CallKit saves the incoming calls in the phone app's history.
Is there a way to disable this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

From iOS11, there is a way to do prevent adding call kit calls in the call history.

```
     let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName:"AppName")
     if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        providerConfiguration.includesCallsInRecents = false
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the property **remoteHandle** from **CXCallUpdate**.

If this property is removed, your app won't be suggested in Contacts as well.

Comment: No, that will just result in Unknown Caller to appear on the CallKit incoming-call screen. The call will still be showing up in Recents (also as Unknown Caller).